# how to read complex cookie data - jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have got to read and manipulate a cookie that looks like this:

```
cookiename = 9918430821007~12.00 | 7C9918430831006~3.00 | 7C7501031311309~50.30
```

The above cookie has 3 values, each separated by "|"
Each value is separated by a "~"

The first item(9918430821007) represents a unique product id
The second (12.00) represents the amount in usd

I am stuck in  the following:

How do i check if the product ID exist when adding a product to a shopping cart(to prevent duplicate entries)?

I have got to make a total $ of all usd values, how to make the total of all these amout pairs (12.00,3.00,50.30..etc)

FYI i am using jquery 1.72 + jquery.cookie.js

Any help would much be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can’t you change that cookie data format? Using some kind of serialization, f.e. JSON, would be highly preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this ?

```
var Products = $.cookie('cookiename').split(' | ')
// Products= ['9918430821007~12.00', '7C9918430831006~3.00', '7C7501031311309~50.30']
```

You could then do this:

```
Products[0].split('~')[0] // 9918430821007
Products[0].split('~')[1] // 12.00
```

...or something of that sort. Hope this helps!

**Edit** [Here's a jsFiddle to help](http://jsfiddle.net/55PJW/)

Comment: I tried this..but this would always return the first value pair(9918430821007) & (12.00)

Comment: the second pair will never be executed (7C9918430831006~3.00)

Comment: Thanks for your help & effort anyway

Comment: @Wasiim if the cookie value is this: '9918430821007~12.00 | 7C9918430831006~3.00 | 7C7501031311309~50.30'

then using `split(' | ')` should result in an array where each item holds a different product (i.e. different set of 1234~12.00 items). Are you getting a different result ?

Comment: When i do the split, i get the array: ['9918430821007~12.00', '7C9918430831006~3.00', '7C7501031311309~50.30']

Comment: and [0] would always mean: 9918430821007, [1] mean: 12.00

Comment: Ok, that's good then. So you can now use the array index to go through each product like so: `Products[0]..` for the first product, `Products[1]...` for the second etc..   makes sense ?

Comment: The issue is: How to get all the [0] and all the [1] for ALL values?

Comment: Added a jsFiddle to the original answer - hope this helps (-!